# How do I make it to where Boat object removee only prints out the recent added item to "removed" Array

Tags: java, arrays

removed is an array that contains a list of boat objects but I want it to print the boat object that was just added instead of the whole removed array list.

Any way to do this?

```
public void removedLog() {

    // for each boat in this log
    for (int i = 0; i < removed.size(); i++) {

        Boat removee = removed.get(i);


        // print boat info and where it is.
        System.out.printf("%8s%10s%10s%10s      $%.6s%n%n", removee.getName().toUpperCase(),
                "REMOVED", removee.getGasAmount().toUpperCase(), removee.getIceAmount().toUpperCase(), removee.getPrice());
    }
}
```

Comment: question is not quite clear. Your loop seems to get each element in your array and assign it to `removee` and print them. What it the functionality that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: how do I loop it to only print out the last element of the array

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Couldn't you instead just access the last item in the array?

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to use `ArrayList` for this. So you can get the last inserted item like as follows,

```
 Boat removee = arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1);
```

---

Edited

Import

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Create ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Boat> arrayList =  new ArrayList<Boat>();
```

Add boat objects to array list

```
arrayList.Add(new Boat());
```

Comment: how would I use arrayList sorry I'm super new to java -.-

Comment: @JoshuaWoohMcLendon I have edited answer please find it. For more details please refer this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

If you cant avoid the loop, you can try this.
Declare the `Boat removee` outside the loop, and move the print statement to after the loop.

If you can avoid the loop, you should try the solution from `Saveendra Ekanayake`.